# Function not working in contextual filter

Tags: 7, views

I have a function in my custom module that return the nids for drafts in array.

```
function get_all_drafts(){
    $query = db_query("select bid from kom_draft");
    $res = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach($res as $bid){
        $output[] = $bid->bid;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

and following code is used in contextual filter nid ( php code text area )

```
$nids = get_all_drafts();
return implode('+',$nids);
```

and checked the multiple value checkbox but its not working, i checked the query and there in not value to compare.

when i use the same code on tpl file i am getting proper output that is + separated nids.

Comment: Could you add some devel call for getting value of $nids before you return the imploded string? E.g. $nids = get_all_drafts(); dpm($nids); return implode('+',$nids);

Answer (score 0):

I just get it done by enabling validation criteria, I selected content validation with node content type and its working fine.